# spring-boot saml: configure service provider entityId using a yaml file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-saml2

hello everyone is there a way to configure the entityID of the service provider in the following configuration:

```
spring:
  security:
    saml2:
      relyingparty:
        registration:
          myapp:
            signing:
              credentials:
                - private-key-location: "classpath:private.pem"
                  certificate-location: "classpath:public.pem"
            identityprovider:
              entity-id: HERE I NEED MY CUSTOM ADDRESS
              singlesignon:
                sign-request: false
                url: https://.../auth/realms/saml-demo/protocol/saml
```

Currently the identity provider is always receiving the following format:

```
{baseUrl}/saml2/service-provider-metadata/{registrationId}
```

But instead of that I want something like :

```
http://localhost:8080/saml2/service-provider-metadata/myapp
```

Is this any way possible to do it ? I checked the official documentation and I found the format which is the following

```
spring:
  security:
    saml2:
      relyingparty:
        okta:
          identityprovider:
            entity-id: ...
            singlesignon.sign-request: false
```

but it does not work. [Link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/saml2/login/authentication-requests.html) for the documentation

Does anyone know how to make it work ? thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hello everyone sorry for posting the question and 30 minutes after reply to my own question with a solution but I found out that the official documentation is just wrong and in order to edit that value of the issuer you have to have the following format:

```
spring:
  security:
    saml2:
      relyingparty:
        registration:
          myapp:
            signing:
              credentials:
                - private-key-location: "classpath:private.pem"
                  certificate-location: "classpath:public.pem"
            entity-id: "http://localhost:8080/saml2/service-provider-metadata/myapp"
```

Hope it helps